# Develop custom visual web part in SharePoint 2010 foundation and deploy it in sharepoint 2010 server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Is is possible to develop a custom visual web part in SharePoint 2010 Foundation, and then package it as wsp and deploy it to SharePoint 2010 Server?

I have a development environment which is having SharePoint Foundation and I don't want to upgrade to install a full standalone sharepoint 2010 server in local machine, so I want to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly possible and there should not be any issue!

**NOTE:** Until you are utilising any Enterprise or Standard feature like SharePoint.Taxonomy, MetaData, Business Connectivity Services etc. You will not be able to access Enterprise or Standard features with SharePoint Object Model when developing in SharePoint Foundation!

Comment: Sorry this is wrong. The dlls arent included for things like SharePoint.Taxonomy. So anything in standard that has a DLL won't be accessible for development.

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: That's obvious! no worries

Answer (score 0):

This will only be okay if you aren't using any of the removed namespaces.

Arsalan unfortunately isn't aware of this,

Examples are the Enterprise Content Management DLLs ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559357.aspx))

Look here at what is available. [MSDN SharePoint 2010 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539432%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: @HughWood, it was quite obvious as said by Prashant, you shouldn't use "Arsalan unfortunately isn't aware of this" such statements!

Comment: Well you youngsters :P nowadays lol

Comment: @HughWood, we youngsters are the next generation ;)